# Send multiple type parameter with Alamofire to API - Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I need to send two parameter like bellow to `API` with `Alamofire`:

`function: String` And `json: ModelPostFiltersShort`.

`function: String`: this is a string name.

And this (`json: ModelPostFiltersShort`) parameter is like bellow:

```
struct ModelPostFiltersShort: Codable {
    var languages, types: [String]
    var categories: [Int]
    var page: Int
}
```

How can I send these parameters with `Alamofire`?

```
let params : [String : ?] = ["function": function,"??": ??]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params????).responseJSON {
}
```

In android I am sending values like bellow:

```
@POST("/web_service/mobile/rest")
Observable<Response<List<GetShortTermCoursesModel>>> getResultFilters(@Query("function") String function,
                                                                      @Body SendFiltersShortCourseModel sendFiltersShortCourseModel);
```

This `@Body SendFiltersShortCourseModel sendFiltersShortCourseModel` parameter has not name!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create model that holds all the body (request parameters)

```
struct RequestParameters: Codable {
    let languages: [String]
    let types: [String]
    let categories: [Int]
    let page: Int
}
```

Use the code below to prepare and send the request

```
func sendRequest() {

        let requestParameters = RequestParameters(languages: ["fa"], types: ["modular"], categories: [70], page: 1)
        // create full parameters model

        let encoder = JSONEncoder() // create encoder to encode your request parameters to Data

        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(requestParameters) else {
            return
        } // create data

        let url = URL(string: "https://reg.mou.ir/web_service/mobile/rest?function=getShortTermCourses")! // create url

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url) // create url request

        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") // add all the headers you need

        urlRequest.httpBody = data // add your parameters
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        // send your request
        Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseString { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let responseString):
                print("Success: \(responseString)") // get your response here
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)") // get error if it appears here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Dmitry. Get me result but don't work filters (let modelPostFiltersShort = ModelPostFiltersShort(languages: ["en"], types: ["some"], categories: [1,2,3], page: 10)) get me all values from API.

Comment: @ jo jo. I need to see documentation of your api. At this point I can't guess what is wrong. Probably some keys are wrong or something else.

Comment: @ Dmitry. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSONEncoder` to get the `data` from `ModelPostFiltersShort's` instance and then convert it to `String` using `String's` `init(data:encoding:)`, i.e.

```
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(obj) //this is body of the request
    let params = ["function": function] //these are query params
    if let url = URL(string: "YOUR_URL") {
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url) // create url request
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.httpBody = data
        //now create Alamofire request here...
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

`obj` is the instance of type `ModelPostFiltersShort`

Comment: Get me this error:  Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength

Comment: Where have you passed these params?

Comment: In android I am sending values like bellow:

    @POST("/web_service/mobile/rest")
    Observable<Response<List<GetShortTermCoursesModel>>> getResultFilters(@Query("function") String function,
                                                                          @Body SendFiltersShortCourseModel sendFiltersShortCourseModel);

This `@Body SendFiltersShortCourseModel sendFiltersShortCourseModel` parameter has not name!! but you are using "json" name???